Excel add-in, rowliner, not working on 64 bit machine
There's an excel add-in called Rowliner which has exactly the functionality I'm after.  Unfortunately it doesn't work for 64 bit machines.  Can anyone advise if there's an up to date solution for this?
Thanks
http://www.cpearson.com/excel/rowliner.htm#google_vignette

Questions seeking product, service, or learning material recommendations are off-topic because they become outdated quickly and attract opinion-based answers. Instead, describe your situation and the specific problem you're trying to solve. Share your research. Here are a few suggestions on how to properly ask this type of question.

It lacks support for 64-bit versions of Office, but it does support 32-bit versions of Office; it works regardless of whether it's on a 32-bit version of Windows or a 64-bit version of Windows. If you must use the 64-bit version of Excel, you will have to find your own alternative to the add-on. You don't specify what version of Excel you are using.
